# Putty not showing full path?

Tags: centos, ssh, apache-2.4, centos7, putty

Pretty sure this is a stupid question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere...

When I use some command lines in Putty, (like top -c) the output is not complete, and I can't see the whole path
[putty output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1RSg.jpg)

Does anyone know who to make Putty show the entire lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not with **putty** in that case but with `top`. I don't know if you have any other app with issues, in the case of `top` you can move the display to the right/left with the keyboard arrows, this should allow you to view the full command path. **But...**

You might want to use other settings too, as doing `top -c` will show the full path for the process, and it will still refresh every second or so, and you will have every process changing position all the time. Not good.

So, I prefer to run `ps auxww` instead, if you need `top`, you could wrap a 1 second capture of `top` with `top -cbn1 -w256`, that would set the `-b` for batch, the `-c` for command and the `-n1` for iterations while the wrap for 256 width.